# Sort wordpress posts by week

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to sort Wordpress posts by week all the way till the current date.

However, Wordpress only provides a query for a set date.

```
<?php 
    $weekly_query = new WP_Query(array( 'year' => date('Y'), 'w' => date('W'), 'posts_per_page' => 99, 'paged' => get_query_var('paged'))); 
    while( $weekly_query->have_posts() ): $weekly_query->the_post(); 
?>
```

Is there a way to make this query loop itself and sort posts week by week, all the way from (for example) 2010 till 2013?

Comment: After a bit of thinking, I'm thinking $yearval = 2010; 'year' => $yearval, and if loop is done and $yearval != 2013, $yearval++ ...

Comment: Also, for week - $weekval == 1, 'w' => $weekval and if $weekval != 53, $weekval++, else $weekval == 1;